# How do I patch a kernel bug?

Tags: boot, kernel, patch

Sometimes I can't boot my laptop - it gets stuck here:

[image]

Then I have to do a hard-reset and it's fine. I checked the boot logs and this is what I think it's causing it (nevermind the timestamp inconsistencies):

```
[38.377595] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
[38.377821] IP: [<ffffffffa01f6d7b>] r600_pcie_gart_tlb_flush+0xeb/0x110 [radeon]
[38.378065] PGD 121491067 PUD 121492067 PMD 0 
[38.378214] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/tPJpSzb4) is the full log.

I found [the patches](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/stable-queue.git;a=summary) but I have no idea about which to use and how.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/11249/12864)?

Comment: No, user in that thread asked only about how to apply patch - what I essentially want too; but I also need some help about deciding which patch should I use or if I should just do a dist-upgrade to get a new kernel?

Comment: You are better off upgrading your kernel. Because you don't exactly know what bug hit you and hence, can't choose the most appropriate patch. Moreover, it is highly likely the latest kernel should have patched up your bug already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It essentially upgraded the kernel without making my hands dirty with patching the kernel myself.

I am not sure if it will help with my boot fail issue - have to boot a few times to see but I will report back. As far as the question is concerned, it is resolved.

Comment: Hopefully it's that simple! You can always post a new question later if you have more clues or data.

Comment: So far 5 boots and 0 problems :) Hope It stays this way.

Comment: I can confirm this fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was fixed by upgrading the kernel, but this doesn't answer the opening question and is unsatisfying for everyone arriving here hoping for an answer.

So, how does one, generally, patch a kernel bug when patch files are available?

Comment: Did you follow the link from the first comment after the opening question?  Also, your answer is a comment, not an answer, so it is not really in the right place.