# Surface Pro 2 keyboard cover not working in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, surface

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Surface Pro 2 at the moment and it seems to be working fine, except for the fact that neither one of my keyboard covers is working. The keys light up on my Type Cover 2, but nothing registers and the same is true for my old Touch Cover!

I'm therefore unable to complete the installation, cannot enter a username and so on...

How can I fix it?

Thanks from Austria! :)

P.S.: I used this guide: [Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is proprietary hardware the linux kernel just can't seem to handle it yet. 
See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175657, 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64811 and the follow up discussion: 
http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-Add-HID-s-to-hid-microsoft-driver-of-Surface-Type-Touch-Cover-2-to-fix-bug-td790242.html. 
So kernel people seem to be already on it. I couldn't find out if the patch landed in any upstream kernel yet. 
If you don't want to wait you can try to compile a custom kernel with their patch included. Here are two resources with some information: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelCustomBuild,
[Correct way to apply patches to your kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11249/correct-way-to-apply-patches-to-your-kernel)

**Disclaimer**
Never tried this myself

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I'll stick to my virtual machine with Ubuntu on my Surface Pro until this is really fixed and enjoy the full experience on my main rig at home :)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem while trying to get the wireless drivers working.

I am using a Surface Pro 2 with a type cover and a fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04-1.
I installed ndiswrapper, but I doubt this is related to this.  Then I installed wine, and I set the "Windows Version" to "Windows 8" in the Concigure Wine Application.  Works perfectly on my machine. :)